# Can two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3 $form a basis of a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ form a basis of a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Answer (score 2):

Vector in $\mathbb R^{3}$ do not even belong to $\mathbb R^{2}$ so the question does not make sense.

However, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ span a space that is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: Hmm, I would argue the question does make sense, but that the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Take any two linearly independent vectors, they are a basis for (a space just like) $\mathbb{R}^2$. Or just pick $(0, 1, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 0)$, and you get the standard $x y$ plane.

Comment: Sure. Let's say I have vectors (1,2,0) and (2,3,0). These for sure don't span $R^3$ because the system of equations is inconsistent. How do I know if they span $R^2$?

Comment: As sets a plane in $\mathb R^{3}$ and $\mathb R^{2}$ are not the same. You are only saying that two vectors in $\mathb R^{3}$ can span a space **isomorphic** to $\mathb R^{2}$. There is a technical difference between these.

Comment: @atn $(1,2,0)$ and $(2,3,0)$ are linearly independent, hence they span a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ of dimension $2$. That subspace, like all subspaces of dimension $2$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, but is not equal to $\mathbb R^2$ as the vectors don't have the right number of coordinates to be in $\mathbb R^2$. Not sure what you mean by "the system of equations is inconsistent."